# Log4net logging to Oracle throwing error when logging to Number fields?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, log4net

I have been battling this issue for quite some time.  When I try to log to a Number(38,0) field in an Oracle 11g database.  I get this error:

> log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception
>   while writing to database System.FormatException: Input string was not
>   in a correct format.    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str,
>   NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info,
>   Boolean parseDecimal)

```
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":my_param" />
        <dbType value="Int32" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{my_param}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
```

I have tried setting the size of the Int32.  I have tried decimal and also decimal with setting the scale and precision.  I am unsure what else to do but I know the value present is numeric.

Here is some code calling the logger to log and also where the value is being defaulted.

```
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties[":my_param"] = 132;
log.Info("Application Start");  //Error occurs here in the output window
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove that colon when you're adding the my_param property to the LogicalThreadContext.

i.e.

```
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["my_param"] = 132;
```

Currently your use of the %property syntax is mismatched with the name of the property you're adding.

Comment: I had figured it out, but was unable to answer my own question.  Thanks mate.